# Is there a way to combine two observables that are guaranteed to be in sync?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Let's say I have two variables that I want to combine that both come from the same source observable,and I can guarantee that they're both going to be updated at the same time. To give a contrived example:

```
const numbers = new BehaviorSubject(1);
const numsPlus = numbers.pipe(map(x => x + 1));
const numsMinus = numbers.pipe(map(x => x - 1));

numbers.next(2);
numbers.next(3);
```

What I want is a way to combine these such that the emissions would look like this:

```
[2, 0]
[3, 1]
[4, 2]
```

If I use `combineLatest`, I get this:

```
combineLatest(numsPlus, numsMinus)
    .subscribe(console.log);

[2, 0]
[3, 0]
[3, 1]
[4, 1]
[4, 2]
```

A fair thing to mention is that it might be better to do:

```
numbers.pipe(map(x => [x + 1, x - 1]))
```

Let's just say that this is an older system that I didn't design, and changing it to do something different is... complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [`zip`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/zip).

```js
zip(numsMinus, numsPlus).subscribe(console.log)
```

Output:

```js
[2, 0]
[3, 1]
[4, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to zip might be to combine [`combineLatest`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest) with a suitable [`debounceTime`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/debounceTime).

```
combineLatest([numsPlus, numsMinus]).pipe(debounceTime(<your-value>))
```

```
const numbers = interval(1000).pipe(take(5));
const numsPlus = numbers.pipe(map((x) => x + 1));
const numsMinus = numbers.pipe(map((x) => x - 1));

combineLatest([numsPlus, numsMinus])
  .pipe(debounceTime(100))
  .subscribe({ next: (values) => console.log(values) });

[1,-1]
[2,0]
[3,1]
[4,2]
[5,3]
```

[RxJS playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-dawn-6sis77?file=/src/index.ts)

Comment: That's fair, though this is code that's performance-sensitive, and putting it into a new macro task seems like it could hurt performance. Otherwise, it's a legitimate solution.